# Django static files to AWS S3 return 403 forbidden

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, python-django-storages

I'm working on a Django(3) project which is deployed at Heroku. I'm trying to connect AWS S3 using Django Storages to upload Static and Media files to S3 Bucket.

> **Note:** I have googled a lot and tried every solution I found, but nothing solved my issue, so don't mark this as duplicate, please!

I have created an S3 bucket with the Public access enabled and added the following CORS configuration:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Also, created an IAM user with programmatic access and gives the permission as `S3FullAccess`

And here's what I have in `**settings.py**`

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'us-east-1'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage'
```

If I open files from the bucket directly I can see the file in the browser, but when I load my site (pythonist.org) these files return with `403 forbidden`

Here's the response from browser's Network tab for a file:

```
Summary
URL: https://s3.amazonaws.com/pythonist.org/css/normalize.css
Status: 403 Forbidden
Source: Network
Initiator: 
pythonist.org:18
```

Don't know what's wrong here,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you really sure the bucket is public? When you say, you open directly from bucket admin, are you still able to access the file when removing all `GET` parameters in the URL? (I guess not because it should lead to the exact same URL as `https://s3.amazonaws.com/pythonist.org/css/normalize.css`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your bucket is not publicly accessible. Your public bucket should have a bucket policy like this one (example with some deleted attributes):

```
{
    "Id": "Policy1640778083903",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1640778050694",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::pythonist.org",
                "arn:aws:s3:::pythonist.org/*"
            ],
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "YOUR_IAM_USER"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1640778082281",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::pythonist.org/*",
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Your IAM user has any permission while the public can only get the objects (not from the root directory here, change to your needs). Create your policy with [AWS Policy Generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html)

Comment: Add this policy to the bucker and replaced the `IAM_User` to the `IAM user name` but it says `Invalid principal in policy`

Comment: Now you should be able to copy-paste. Make sure the bucket ARN is correct.